# How to reproduce the error 'InvalidArgumentError : expected multiples argument to be a vector of length 2 but got length 3' while using tf.tile

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I implemented some code with `tf.tile` and got this error message:

> InvalidArgumentError : expected multiples argument to be a vector of length 2 but got length 3

The code is quite complicated and I can't directly find out what caused the error. So I made some dummy codes to reproduce the error, so that I may understand which value was the source of the error. However, I can't figure out how to reproduce this error with dummy code.

I tried to do it like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])
b = tf.tile(a, [1,1,3])
```

This gives me error the message:

> Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'Tile_0' with input shapes:~~

Can anybody provide some example code that can reproduce my original error?

Comment: What is the output you want to achieve?

Comment: @vijaym I just want to figure out what I did wrong with my code, and I need to understand what caused that error message. The related code is at : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/core/kernels/tile_ops.cc 
I can find the same error message, but I can't reproduce it

Comment: Did you discover? I'm running  into the same error :)

Comment: @Roelant Actually I asked this question long time ago and now I don't remember what I wanted to do at that time. However, from the instruction from tensorflow I found that the length of the second argument (multiples) must be the same as the dimension of the first argument (input).

Answer (score 0):

After four years, I suspect a direct solution won't be useful, so here's a general explanation for the other 2,000 people that have viewed this in the meantime!

From [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile):

> This operation creates a new tensor by replicating `input` `multiples` times. The output tensor's i'th dimension has `input.dims(i) * multiples[i]` elements, and the values of `input` are replicated `multiples[i]` times along the 'i'th dimension. For example, tiling `[a b c d]` by `[2]` produces `[a b c d a b c d]`.

Your `a` vector is a rank-2 tensor, so `tf.tiles` expects multiples to have 2 elements, but your `multiples` has 3 elements. You must match `a`'s dimension with the length of `multiples`.